# How do I strip multiple (optional) parts of a SQL string using .NET Regular Expressions?

Tags: .net, sql, regex

I've been working on this for a few hours now and can't find any help on it. Basically, I'm trying to strip a SQL string into various parts (fields, from, where, having, groupBy, orderBy). I refuse to believe that I'm the first person to ever try to do this, so I'd like to ask for some advise from the StackOverflow community. :)

To understand what I need, assume the following SQL string:

```
select * from table1 inner join table2 on table1.id = table2.id 
where field1 = 'sam' having table1.field3 > 0 
group by table1.field4 order by table1.field5
```

I created a regular expression to group the parts accordingly:

```
select\s+(?<fields>.+)\s+from\s+(?<from>.+)\s+where\s+(?<where>.+)\s+having\s+(?<having>.+)\s+group\sby\s+(?<groupby>.+)\s+order\sby\s+(?<orderby>.+)
```

This gives me the following results:

```
fields => *
from => table1 inner join table2 on table1.id = table2.id
where => field1 = 'sam'
having => table1.field3 > 0
groupby => table1.field4
orderby => table1.field5
```

The problem that I'm faced with is that if *any* part of the SQL string is missing after the 'from' clause, the regular expression doesn't match.

To fix that, I've tried putting each optional part in it's own `(...)?` group but that doesn't work. It simply put all the optional parts (where, having, groupBy, and orderBy) into the 'from' group.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to do this perfectly using .Net regular expressions; you need a stack-based parser.

If you don't see why, consider the following two valid queries:

```
SELECT 'I\'m from Kansas', 'where the grass is greener'     
FROM Minnesota 
WHERE Grass = 'Blue'
```

---

```
SELECT 
    ID,
    Name IN (SELECT Name From Employees WHERE Rank > 4),
    Grade
FROM Employees
WHERE Rank < 4
```

---

## EDIT

To answer the question:

```
new Regex(@"

    ^
    select\s+(?<fields>.+?)
        \s+ from       \s+ (?<from>    .+?)
    (?: \s+ where      \s+ (?<where>   .+?))?
    (?: \s+ having     \s+ (?<having>  .+?))?
    (?: \s+ group\s+by \s+ (?<groupby> .+?))?
    (?: \s+ order\s+by \s+ (?<orderby> .+ ))?
    $", 

        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

(Re-tested)
This will not handle nested queries or string literals

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and I definitely see your point. However, I don't need to support nested sql queries for my requirement...

Comment: Your edit does not appear to be valid. I tested it against the query that I posted in my question and each part only returns a single character when using .+?  -- Regards